# Rewrite this javascript code to typescript

Tags: typescript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Initialize the plugin
    $('#my_popup').popup({
        color: '#09344c',
        opacity: 1,
        transition: '0.3s',
        scrolllock: true
    });

    // Initialize the plugin
    $('#my_info_popup').popup({
        color: '#09344c',
        opacity: 1,
        transition: '0.3s',
        scrolllock: true
    });

});
```

Sorry, I'm super new to typescript and I only need this for now so I thought I'll just ask. This code is to activate a pop-up. Basically getting the id of the div and calling the popup function on it that accepts these params.

EDIT: NVM I guess typescript errors don't mean anything, I just ran the compile and it just spit javascript out.

Comment: If you ignore the errors they mean nothing. If you don't ignore them they can help you catch errors and improve the quality of your code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> I guess typescript errors don't mean anything, I just ran the compile and it just spit javascript out.

The errors detected by TypeScript are usually indicative of a potential problem, although in your case you may be simply missing type information for an external library. The compiler has a flag that allows you to decide whether you want to emit JavaScript when there are errors.

```
--noEmitOnError
```

As you are using jQuery, you can improve auto-completion and compilation information by using the jQuery type definition. Normally, these are managed using a `pckage.json` file and loaded from NPM. You'll find all of the type definitions under the `@types` organisation. Here is the [jQuery type definition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery).

You can find more of these on the [Definitely Typed Types Search page](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).

If you don't want auto-completion, type checking, and other helpful tooling around the third party library, you can simply make it entirely dynamic. TypeScript allows you to keep dynamic types where you want to:

```
declare var $: any;
```

In some cases, where the external code is tangential to your application and lightly used, this is fine. In your case, your code is so dependant on jQuery that the most likely errors will be in calls made to the jQuery API - so the type definition will be super useful.